# What should I do to have a symbolic solution in minimization? Is this possible?

Tags: sympy, nonlinear-optimization, minimize

I want to solve y variable from "expression" equation in terms of p_s and p_h. I solved it with "solve" method but does not solution because with this parameters it is not possible. I thought, I can solve it with minimization but I don't know how can I get a solution in terms of p_s and p_s. with the code as follows, I get a solution without symbolic form even though I have not left an amount for p_s and p_h.

```
def func():
    
    α , h0 , π , τ , θ = 0.7 , 1 , 0.05 , 0.02 , 0.02
    y , p_h , p_s = sympy.symbols('y p_h p_s')
    
    c_r  = α*((y/(1+π))+τ)
    s_r  = ((1-α)/p_s)*((y/(1+π))+τ)
    c0_o = (y/(1+π))-((p_h*θ*h0**2)/(1+π))+τ

    expression = (((c_r**α)*(s_r**(1-α))) - ((c0_o**α)*(h0**(1-α))))**2
    lam = lambdify(y, expression , modules=['numpy'])
    
    return lam




x0 = 1.5


res  = minimize(lam , x0, method='Nelder-Mead')


res
```

Could you help me what can I do to have this form of solution?

Comment: Does this run?  If so what is `res` result?  Or what error?  Often with these `lambdified` questions, I need to see what that `lambdify` has produced, namely the python code shown by `help(lam)`.  Without running the code myself I can't "visualize" what is happening.

Comment: the result is:  final_simplex: (array([[9.50737950e+28],
       [4.75368975e+28]]), array([-5.58381892e+19, -3.43724374e+19]))
           fun: -5.58381892382599e+19
       message: 'Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded.'
          nfev: 200
           nit: 100
        status: 1
       success: False
             x: array([9.5073795e+28])

Answer (score 0):

Modifying `func` to `print(expression)`:

```
In [9]: f = func()
0.93397441894595*(0.542881452689825*((0.952380952380952*y + 0.02)/p_s)**0.3*(y + 0.021)**0.7 - (-0.02*p_h + y + 0.021)**0.7)**2
```

`y`, `p_s` and `p_h` are symbols in the expression.

and the help

```
In [11]: help(f)
Help on function _lambdifygenerated:

_lambdifygenerated(y)
    Created with lambdify. Signature:
    
    func(y)
    
    Expression:
    
    0.93397441894595*(0.542881452689825*((0.952380952380952*y +...
    
    Source code:
    
    def _lambdifygenerated(y):
        return 0.93397441894595*(0.542881452689825*((0.952380952380952*y + 0.02)/p_s)**0.3*(y + 0.021)**0.7 - (-0.02*p_h + y + 0.021)**0.7)**2
```

If I run the function with a scalar:

```
In [17]: print(f(1.5))
1.68002552835784*(-(1 - 0.0131492439184747*p_h)**0.7 + 0.606718138605891*(1/p_s)**0.3)**2
```

This is a sympy expression, same as `expression.subs({'y':1.5})`.

```
In [14]: from scipy.optimize import minimize

In [15]: res  = minimize(f , 1.5, method='Nelder-Mead')
TypeError: Cannot convert expression to float
```

That's the same as if I tried `float(f(1.5))`.  `minimize` works with numbers, and wants `f` to return a number (or at least something it can turn into a float).  It calls `f` for various values, and tries find the smallest.

For someone trying to use `fsolve` with sympy:
[How to convert class 'sympy.core' to 'number' or 'float' for optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63160024/how-to-convert-class-sympy-core-to-number-or-float-for-optimization)