# How can I solve the analytical case as a numerical case?

Tags: python, sympy, numerical-methods, minimization

I want to solve y variable in terms of p_h and p_s. From analytical case, it is not solved and the output given parameters is empty list. I want to solve it as a numerical case. How can I do that? How can I solve y in terms of p_h and p_s with numerical solution?

```py
def func():
    
    α , h0 , π , τ , θ = 0.7 , 1 , 0.05 , 0.02 , 0.02
    y , p_h , p_s = sympy.symbols('y p_h p_s')
    
    c_r  = α*((y/(1+π))+τ)
    s_r  = ((1-α)/p_s)*((y/(1+π))+τ)
    c0_o = (y/(1+π))-((p_h*θ*h0**2)/(1+π))+τ

    expression = (((c_r**α)*(s_r**(1-α))) - ((c0_o**α)*(h0**(1-α))))
    y00 = solve(expression, y,  dict = True)

    return y00

func()
```

I know I can not solve it from minimization because this method does not give me a symbolic solution. So with which way I can solve it? could you give me an example?

Note: I can not change the value of parameters.

Comment: This is a continuation of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75582265/what-should-i-do-to-have-a-symbolic-solution-in-minimization-is-this-possible.  As noted there, `expression` is a function of 3 variables.  If `solve` gives an empty result, it can't produce an analytical solution for `y` as a function of `p_s` and `p_h`.  Of course a numerical solution for `y` isn't possible either.  Substituting numeric values for those variables might work - at least it can reduce the problem to solving for just one variable.

Comment: When asking a question that's a repeat or restatement of a previous, reference those, and try to build on the previous help.  I recognized this repeat because I answered your previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your equation changed slightly to use exact rational numbers instead of floats (using nsimplify, also I assumed that symbols are positive):

```
In [55]: import sympy

In [56]:     α , h0 , π , τ , θ = map(sympy.nsimplify, [0.7 , 1 , 0.05 , 0.02 , 0.02])
    ...:     y , p_h , p_s = sympy.symbols('y p_h p_s', positive=True)
    ...: 
    ...:     c_r  = α*((y/(1+π))+τ)
    ...:     s_r  = ((1-α)/p_s)*((y/(1+π))+τ)
    ...:     c0_o = (y/(1+π))-((p_h*θ*h0**2)/(1+π))+τ
    ...: 
    ...:     expression = (((c_r**α)*(s_r**(1-α))) - ((c0_o**α)*(h0**(1-α))))

In [57]: expression
Out[57]: 
                                                     7/10            3/10
                               7/10  3/10 ⎛2⋅y    7 ⎞     ⎛20⋅y   1 ⎞    
                      7/10   10    ⋅3    ⋅⎜─── + ───⎟    ⋅⎜──── + ──⎟    
  ⎛  2⋅pₕ   20⋅y   1 ⎞                    ⎝ 3    500⎠     ⎝ 21    50⎠    
- ⎜- ──── + ──── + ──⎟     + ────────────────────────────────────────────
  ⎝  105     21    50⎠                             3/10                  
                                              10⋅pₛ
```

Now we can simplify this a bit and with a linear substitution reduce it to a simple radical equation involving your three symbols:

```
In [63]: eq = numer(expression.simplify().subs(1000*y + 21, z + 20*p_h))

In [64]: eq
Out[64]: 
       3/10  3/5   3/10  7/10    3/10  7/10            
- 10⋅42    ⋅5   ⋅pₛ    ⋅z     + 3    ⋅7    ⋅(20⋅pₕ + z)
```

At this point it would be easy to substitute some values for `p_h` and `p_s` and then solve numerically. You can also think qualitatively about how the solutions will look given that you have two terms and each only involves one of your two parameters. We can't get an analytic solution from here but we can go a bit further and turn it into a polynomial equation:

```
In [65]: from sympy.solvers.solvers import unrad

In [67]: unrad(eq)[0]
Out[67]: 
                    10                       9                        8  2                     7  3
24586240000000000⋅pₕ   + 12293120000000000⋅pₕ ⋅z + 2765952000000000⋅pₕ ⋅z  + 368793600000000⋅pₕ ⋅z 

                    6  4                   5  5                 4  6                3  7           
 + 32269440000000⋅pₕ ⋅z  + 1936166400000⋅pₕ ⋅z  + 80673600000⋅pₕ ⋅z  + 2304960000⋅pₕ ⋅z  + 43218000

   2  8              9                      3  7         10
⋅pₕ ⋅z  + 480200⋅pₕ⋅z  - 1250000000000000⋅pₛ ⋅z  + 2401⋅z
```

(Note that this last step introduces spurious roots so any roots found at the end need to be checked to see that they are solutions of the original equations.)

From here for any given values of the parameters you could get a solution by then computing the roots of this polynomial. We can do this efficiently by using lambdify to compute the coefficients and then numpy to compute the roots:

```
In [68]: coeffs = unrad(eq)[0].as_poly(z).all_coeffs()

In [69]: f = lambdify((p_h, p_s), coeffs)

In [70]: f(1, 2)
Out[70]: 
[2401, 480200, 43218000, -9999997695040000, 80673600000, 1936166400000, 32269440000000, 36879360000
0000, 2765952000000000, 12293120000000000, 24586240000000000]

In [71]: np.roots(f(1, 2))
Out[71]: 
array([-8.11124582e+03+1.39337873e+04j, -8.11124582e+03-1.39337873e+04j,
        1.60224916e+04+0.00000000e+00j,  1.23910389e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
        6.79870073e-01+9.82364698e-01j,  6.79870073e-01-9.82364698e-01j,
       -3.30415402e-01+1.06251914e+00j, -3.30415402e-01-1.06251914e+00j,
       -9.69002585e-01+4.28802926e-01j, -9.69002585e-01-4.28802926e-01j])

In [72]: %time np.roots(f(1, 3))
CPU times: user 4 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 4 ms
Wall time: 766 µs
Out[72]: 
array([-1.21335759e+04+2.09006115e+04j, -1.21335759e+04-2.09006115e+04j,
        2.40671518e+04+0.00000000e+00j,  1.02660003e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
        5.76370088e-01+8.12842163e-01j,  5.76370088e-01-8.12842163e-01j,
       -2.68031326e-01+8.99828550e-01j, -2.68031326e-01-8.99828550e-01j,
       -8.21637584e-01+3.68271959e-01j, -8.21637584e-01-3.68271959e-01j])
```

Since this is now quite fast you can try many different values of the parameters and plot the results. Since we did a linear transformation from `y` to `z` you would need to undo that to get values of `y` from the roots for `z` above.

Alternatively rather than seeking explicit solutions you could use the polynomial to answer questions about the solutions of the system using techniques like discriminants, resultants etc. As I said though some care needs to be taken due to the spurious roots that `unrad` will introduce.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SymPy to think about your equation a bit; the form given in `eq` is nice.

It always has the same concavity since there is no zero in the second derivative and there is only one place where the derivative is 0; check with `solve(eq.diff(z,2),z)` and `solve(eq.diff(z),z)`. That being the case, this function is going to be fairly easy to get a numerical solution with `nsolve`; depending on the values, maybe by using continuation.

If `y` and `p_h` are 0 then `eq` is 0. If you increase `p_h` a little, `z` will increase a little, too, and you can solve for the new value of `z`. Continue increasing the value of `p_h` and recomputing the value of `z` until you have reached the desired value of `p_h` using the last found value of `z` as your initial guess to the solver for the new value of `z`:

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> ps=1
>>> ph_z=[]
>>> z0 = 0
>>> for i in range(11):
...     ph = i/2  # or however you want to define ph from i
...     z0 = nsolve(eq.subs(p_s, ps).subs(p_h, ph), z0)
...     ph_z.append((ph, z0.n(3)))
```

You can see your solution pairs (and perhaps just pay attention to the last value if you are only interested in a single value -- in this case 5):

```py
>>> for i in ph_z:print(i)
(0.0, 0)
(0.5, 0.620)
(1.0, 1.72)
(1.5, 3.15)
(2.0, 4.85)
(2.5, 6.80)
(3.0, 8.97)
(3.5, 11.4)
(4.0, 14.0)
(4.5, 16.7)
(5.0, 19.7)
```